# Faster way to search for a string than the boyer moore algorithm?

Tags: c#, boyer-moore

Is there any faster way to search for a string in a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this [site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Single_pattern_algorithms), where you can also see the matching time for each of the algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The Turbo Boyer-Moore algorithm is faster, but requires more space.
http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node15.html

Answer (score 2):

If you know anything specific about the file, there could be faster algorithms.

For example, if the file contains many repeating characters/patterns and you need to do a large number of searches, you could try using Suffix Trees: http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/

Depending on your file and the quantity of searches you need on that one file, the answer for the fastest search algorithm may change.